# "abort" native crash on Android 10 devices

Tags: java, android, react-native, crash

we are getting the following native crash on android 10 devices. I think it has to do something with drawing on `GLSurfaceView` when `hardware acceleration` is enabled but I don't want to disable `hardware acceleration` for the whole app if it is only happening on the surface. Any other alternatives available?

````
  #00  pc 000000000005ed1a  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166)
  #00  pc 0000000000005a49  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+176)
  #00  pc 00000000001f7957  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::skiapipeline::SkiaOpenGLPipeline::swapBuffers(android::uirenderer::renderthread::Frame const&, bool, SkRect const&, android::uirenderer::FrameInfo*, bool*)+94)
  #00  pc 00000000001f6b1d  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::CanvasContext::draw()+364)
  #00  pc 00000000001f6071  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::DrawFrameTask::run()+156)
  #00  pc 0000000000204249  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+164)
  #00  pc 00000000002040a1  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+72)
  #00  pc 000000000000d8ef  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+214)
  #00  pc 00000000000a69b7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20)
  #00  pc 00000000000601af  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) ```
````

Comment: same problem here, no idea what's the issue and where start investigation. Please any suggestment?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Could you please share any pointers to how you addressed this, @Lisitso ?